# this if-else question shows output to be 48

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public class ControlStatement {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int a=25;

       if (a-->a--) {
          {
            a='0';
          }
       }
       else {
          --a;
       }

       System.out.print(a);
   }
}
```

This outputs 48. how did the answer come as 48? can anyone please explain

Comment: `char`s can be converted to `int`, then their ascii value is taken as the `int` value: `'0'` -> `48`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're assigning the character `0` to `a`, *not* the number `0`. (Note that `'0'` is of type `char`, *not* of type `int`). The *character* `0` is equal to the *number* 48 in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Incidentally, the fact that you're allowed to assign a `char` to an `int` is due to [implicit casting](https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/type-casting-java-implicit-explicit-casting/).

Comment: @AchyutDalai Glad I could help :) I actually personally think that the existence of this implicit cast is a bit of a gotcha in Java (because you can end up with situations like this where you think you're assigning an `int` but you're actually assigning a `char` and the compiler won't even warn you about it).